# Kernel is a closed subgroup of a topological group

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a topological space, $H$ be the group of homeomorphisms of $X$, and $T$ be a topological group acting on $X$ on the right. Let $\phi:T\rightarrow H$ be given by $t\mapsto \Pi^t$ where $\Pi^t:X\rightarrow X$ is given by $x\mapsto xt$.

According to my book, $\phi$ is a group homomorphism but it is really not unless the order of function composition is reversed. Moreover, according to the book, $\ker \phi$ is a closed subgroup of $T$ if $X$ is Hausdorff. How can we prove it?

Comment: Did your book introduce a topology on $H$? It 'should' carry the compact-open topology

Comment: @Roundthecorner the topology on $H$? There is no mention of any topology on it.

Comment: Well but you CAN put a topology on $H$ such that $\phi$ becomes continuous and and the set containing only the identity is closed. I am mainly asking to see what the intended solution might be. What book are you reading? Can you say more on what you have tried?

Comment: Well, I guess that $H$ will be Hausdorff too. If so, then singletons will be closed in $H$. Hence, $\ker{\phi}$ being the inverse image of $\{0\}$ is closedbecause $\phi$ is continuous.

Comment: @stressedout so you also put a topology on $H$. $\phi$ is just a group homomorphism.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it seems kind of weird to talk about the kernel being closed but I'm not an expert. I remember something about the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) but I'm not sure if it's relevant here. Does your book mention what topology it defines on $H=\mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$? Wikipedia says that if $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $C(X,Y)$ equipped with the compact-open topology is Hausdorff too. So, if we assume that $H=\mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$ is equipped with the compact-open topology, it will be Hausdorff.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $H = \mathrm{Hom}(X,X)$. That's how $H$ is defined. Right? It turns out that if $X$ is assumed to be Hausdorff, so will be $H$ if it's equipped with the compact-open topology.

Comment: I recommend you to check the index of the book, see where the notion of the group of homeomorphisms has been defined for the first time. Maybe a topology on $H$ has been defined. Otherwise, I can't see how it's possible to proceed if $T$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: The answer just posted gives an argument without assuming compact-open topology @stressedout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there is a problem with the order of composition. I will therefore write $T$ as having a left action, such that $\phi(st)=\phi(s)\phi(t)$.

I believe that putting the compact-open topology on $H$ is the 'better' argument, but it can be done by hand as well.

We will show that the complement of $\ker \phi$ is open. To do this we will find an open neighborhood for any $t\notin \ker\phi$ which is disjoint to $\ker \phi$.

Let $t\notin \ker \phi$. Then $\Pi_t\neq 1_X$. In particular there is $x\in X$ with $tx\neq x$. Because $X$ is Hausdorff there is a open subset $U\subset X$ with $tx\in U$ but $x\notin U$.

Consider now the evaluation at $x$, i.e. $ev_x:T\to X$ $ev_x(t)=tx$. It is continuous. Then clearly $t\in ev_x^{-1}(U)$ and $ev_x^{-1}(U)$ is disjoint from $\ker\phi$. Indeed if $s\in \ker \phi$, then $ev_x(s)=sx=x\notin U$.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what the book means

Comment: Beautiful answer (+1)